# iOS: Facebook SDK makes calls to graph.facebook.com even though SDK is not initialized nor used

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-ios-sdk

As the title suggests. Facebook SDK makes calls to graph.facebook.com when checking in Charles even though I'm not initializing the SDK in app delegate and I've removed all calls to the SDK.

I've made sure that there are no other frameworks in my stack which uses Facebook.

How is this even possible? Doesn't the SDK need to be initialized in App Delegate before it can perform any operations? Is there some clever way Facebook can bypass this through listening to notifications or method swizzling?

A user contacted me about this citing GDPR violations which is why I need this to be resolved.

Clarification: I removed the calls just to investigate this issue. I still need it for authentication purposes, but I don't want graph calls to be made upon launch as this is supposedly a violation of GDPR

Comment: Facebook is a tracking network in it's nature. If you don't make calls to the SDK, why do you even include it?

Comment: Method swizzling is the most likely method Facebook is doing this.

Comment: @swift-lynx Sorry, I should have clarified: I removed the calls just to investigate this issue. I still need it for authentication purposes, but I don't want graph calls to be made upon launch as this is supposedly a violation of GDPR.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Okay! Do you have any sample code on how this can be achieved?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? We are facing the same issue.